# i can't get route url in laravel, here is my code below

Tags: laravel

## This is my about edit view

`<a href="{{url('uprofile/about-edit/'.$value->id)}}" class="btn btn-white btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>`

## This is my route

```
Route::get('uprofile/about-edit/{id}',[AboutController::class,'update']);
```

## and this is function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) 
{
   $data = "hello ram";
    return $data;

}
```

When I click this a href link in UI

then this is occurring:
[image]

Comment: try this:

        <a href="{{url('uprofile/about/edit/'.$value->id)}}" class="btn btn-white btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    
    and :
    Route::get('uprofile/about/edit/{id}',[AboutController::class,'update']);

Comment: use artisan route list command to make sure your route exists

Comment: Do you have any other routes which might be conflicting? Try putting this route at the top of your routes file. And just to make sure - are you `GET`ting this page, not `POST`ing to it from a form?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should drop the idea of using direct urls and better use named Routes.

Try this

```
Route::get('uprofile/about-edit/{id}',[AboutController::class,'update'])->name('profile.update');
```

in in view you should

```
<a href="{{route('profile.update',$value->id)}}" class="btn btn-white btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

```
public function update($id) 
{ 
   dd($id) // will dump and die $id 
   $data = "hello ram";
   return $data;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think named routes will solve the problem?  Named routes are not required?